# Battery indicator disappears and shows frequently

Tags: gnome, indicator

I have a problem with a battery (power) indicator in Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Shell. The indicator disappears and shows every moment when the cable is pluged in. It's ok until I want to click on weather, volume or any other "applet" in the panel, because if I do that at the same moment as the battery indicator dissappears, I click on a wrong applet and that's annoying. Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: have you tried to reinstall the applet that isn't working? (it's a package)

Comment: yep, I had tried it and nothing changed

Comment: is this a bug? if so is it reported at http://launchpad.net ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a bug, but I haven't find it reported anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install another battery indicator:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iaz/battery-status
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install battery-status
```

Comment: The software is apparently not in development any more. Last stable release is from 2010. It might not work on newer Ubuntu releases.